# Real life problem: How many finalists can participate per school?

Tags: fair-division

I have to organize a tournament with following numbers:

I have a total of 1338 participants from different schools, and we need to distribute the 16 finalist's places as fair as possible.

The students are distributed as follwing:

School and number of participiants
a 254
b 211
c 150
d 186
e 158
f 85
g 66
h 105
i 123

Every school gets at least **one** finalist. How do I distribute the 16 final places to the different school?

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Why not the best?

Comment: what do you mean "as fair as possible"? Is it just ensuring there is at least one finalist from each school or any other consideration?

Comment: Sorry, maybe i was unclear. The schools will be allocated starting places at the tournament. The more students, the more starting places. This is not yet a matter of performance. I have 16 starting places at the tournament and would like to distribute them among the schools as fairly as possible.

Comment: Math Lover - there's just one rule, every school get's at least one starting place. School g is very small, so by normal distribution they would'nt get a starting place.

Comment: How is having one finalist from each school fair? If school $A$ has 1000 students and school $B$ has 100 students, there is an unfair bias toward school $B$. If you really want one finalist from each school then each school should have a competition to see which delegate they send.

Comment: Fair enough. You give one starting position to every school as a good gesture and then remaining of $16$ in ratio of their size because you want to be fair. But how is it a probability question? I am just looking at the question tag.

Comment: John, it is not fair and I am aware of that. But that's just one rule I must abide. Every school does send their best students - the question is, which school can send how many of their best students

Answer (score 0):

It seems natural to assign the places roughly proportional to the number of students. Then again, this might easily leave school with $0$ finalists. And we have to deal with rounding.
So the next natural thing is to assign
$$ \lfloor \alpha n+\beta\rfloor$$
finalists to a school with $n$ students. Remains to pick $\alpha$ and $\beta$.
Typically, one fixes one of them and adjusts the other (e.g., by trial and error) until
$$ \sum_{i=1}^9\lfloor \alpha n_i+\beta\rfloor =16.$$
Different strategies are possible (and some correspond to vote counting methods commonly in use to distribute parliamentary seats according to vote counts):

- Set $\beta=0$ and adjust $\alpha$. This method tends to favour large "parties" and may not lead to a "seat" for the smallest school here
- Set $\alpha=\frac{16}{\sum n_i}$ and adjust $\beta$. This method assigns the  naive average as "cost" of a seat and adjusts the offset $\beta$ to make the first seats cheaper until the sum is right
- Set $\beta=1$ and adjust $\alpha$. This is essentially like the first, except that every school gets one seat for free to start with.
- Set $\beta=\frac12$ and adjust $\alpha$. This is somewhere between first and third option
- ...

Comment: Thank you so much, Hagen, that did confirm what I was suspecting! I just was'nt sure, If I was missing something, if there was THE formula to calculate it - but there is several ways of looking at it. Vielen Dank!

Answer (score 0):

The assignment $(3,3,2,2,2,1,1,1,1)$ is optimal for each of the following three objectives:

- Minimize sum of absolute differences between number of seats and quota
- Minimize maximum of absolute differences between number of seats and quota
- Minimize sum of absolute differences between people per seat and $1338/16$